# Grails Solr The import org.apache.solr cannot be resolved

Tags: grails, solr

Recently I changed my solr version from 3.5.0 to 4.8.0 in my grails project. Successfully the jar was downloaded and it is there in the local system but it was not included in project dependencies. It is showing error like `The import org.apache.solr cannot be resolved`

I tried `grails clean` and `grails refresh-dependencies`. But still it I getting the above error. I can someone suggest what might the issue is?

In my `BuildConfig.groovy`   `compile 'org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:4.8.0'`

Comment: I hope the dependency in BuildConfig is present inside `dependencies { .. }` section. Try to remove the old jar from local maven repo or .grails where ever present and then `grails compile`.

Comment: try running `grails compile`

Comment: @dmahapatro No it is not working problem there with org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.1 also

Comment: Then you have to run `grails dependency-report` to see which dependencies are conflicting, removing/excluding them should resolve the issue.